# Scala-Play: Which Javascript client dependency management: WebJars, npm, or?

Tags: scala, typescript, npm, playframework, sbt

I'm working on a Scala-Play +2.5.x Web App and need multiple client-side dependencies including: AngularJS, D3, etc. Furthermore I'd like to develop using Typescript and I'm wondering what choices are there for Javascript dependency management that integrates well with a such technology stack and SBT.

The two main solutions I have found are:

1. Depend on WebJars artifacts, which would be the best integration choice for SBT except I'm not sure how to cope with the Typescript support.
2. `npm` directly though I have no experience using `npm` and can't judge ...
3. Other alternatives?

Comment: How about JSPM? Anyway, anything but WebJars.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Why "anything but WebJars"?

Comment: [WebJars sample app](https://github.com/webjars/sample-play2)